# Debug Live Agent

Tags: liveagent

We are developing a custom prechat page for Live Agent.  It is working exactly how we think it should, with one major exception: it is NOT creating a Case when the chat is accepted.  My question is not how to fix it, but how to debug it.  I've tried putting debug log on both the rep who accepts the chat, and the site guest user.  I have looked at the JS console.  All to no avail, I can't see any info about the Case.  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the javascript library then you can call `liveagent.enableLogging()`. It probably isn't going to give you the level of detail you want, however it might.

Information on this is available at
[enable logging docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_logging_API_enableLogging.htm)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else whom may stumble across this - We had the same issue while utilizing a PreChat Form. I could not get a good debug log at all (very frustrating...). In the end I was able to inspect all of the PreChat form Case values (prior to initializing the Chat) and found that one of the fields was attempting to insert a 36 character input into a 20 character field. Once I increased the field length to 50, it began creating the Case successfully upon Chat initialization.

Comment: The question is about debug. Also, it's not about PreChat but after chat.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can log the preChat API methods except putting some alert statements in your JS script tag.

Are you using liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function setName() {                              
                            if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.sfCaseSubtype}").value == ''){
                                alert("Please pick a detail field.")
                                return false;
                            }                              
                        }                   
                    </script>
```